# What kind of authentication should I be using for a REST API?

Tags: django, authentication

I'm creating an application which talks to a django server and I was wondering how should I be authenticating myself?

I found oauth2 but it sounds like it is for a third party application. 
In my case its just a package of the client and server. Third party applications should not be allowed so oauth2 is not right for me. (unless I misunderstood oauth2)

So my question is what kind of authentication should I be using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are implementing the REST API yourself? Have you looked into the options of using for example http://www.django-rest-framework.org/?

If you use that you get a lot of nice things out of the box, e.g. different possibilities of [authentication](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication).

The documentation says for example:

> **TokenAuthentication:** This authentication scheme uses a simple token-based HTTP Authentication scheme. Token authentication *is appropriate for client-server setups*, such as native desktop and mobile clients.

Comment: I am using DRF but I'm not sure what a good authentication choice would be.

Comment: True. I'm using www.django-rest-frameowrk.org with ActiveDirectory authentication. Working like a charm.

Comment: @Ramis see my updated post. `TokenAuthentication` should be fitting to your use case maybe.